# Where is the P3 pin on the msp430?

Tags: microcontroller, msp430, pins

I'm new to microcontrollers and I'm a little confused about the `P3` pin on the msp430g2553.

In [this](http://mspsci.blogspot.com.ar/2010/05/configuring-inputs-outputs.html) tutorial it mentions setting `P3DIR` and `P3IN` for the push button, but I can't see where `P3` meets the microcontroller on the board itself. The button is labelled as `P1.3` on the board rather than `P3`.

Also, when I searched `msp430g2553.h` I found that `P3` was defined.

Is `P3` a legacy pin or is it actually used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial talks about a different model of the family which may have more I/O ports; however the 2553 does have port P3.

P3 is not a pin, but an 8 bit port therefore (up to) 8 pins P3.0 to P3.7.

Whether the pins are actually available will depend on the package option.

The 20 pin package (such as on the Launchpad) doesn't have enough pins to bring them out to actual device pins (though the logic will be there on the chip; not very useful but still visible to software as an extra register).

However according to [the 2553 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430g2553.pdf%E2%80%8E), the 28 pin package option does bring P3 out as 8 pins.

Comment: So the 20-pin `2553` has the `P3` register, it just doesn't have the corresponding pins?

Comment: That's my reading of the data sheet, yes. If you need the pins, you need the 28 pin package.

Comment: @Josh Voigts One thing to note is that on versions without the P3 pins, internal connection is already hard-wired for minimum power consumption and actual settings of the P3 port don't do anything, so you don't have to worry about code upsetting something in the microcontroller.